# ExtJS 4.2.1 Model - field defaultValue: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, extjs4.2

In my application i got e.g. two Models like this:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Translation', {
    extend: 'App.model.MRModel',
    requires: 'App.model.TranslationItem',

    fields: [
       ...
    ],...
```

and

```
Ext.define('App.model.administration.Station', {
    extend: 'App.model.MRModel',
    requires: [
        'App.model.Translation',
        'App.classes.proxy.ProxyNegotiator'            
    ],

    fields: [
        ...
    ],...
```

and in my Model Station i want to add a field with the default value of a new Translation like this:

```
Ext.define('App.model.administration.Station', {
    extend: 'App.model.MRModel',
    requires: [
        'App.model.Translation',
        'App.classes.proxy.ProxyNegotiator'        
    ],

    fields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'int', convert: null },
        {
            name: 'Name',
            type: 'auto',
            convert: function(value) {
                ...
            },
            defaultValue: new App.model.Translation()
        },
```

though when i am inserting this line with the default Value i get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` 
It seems that the Translation class is not loaded jet.. I dont understnand this cuz i added the class to the requires array...

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defaultValue` is a string or the object that should be the default value.

The problem is that `new App.model.Translation()` probably does not return what you need. It should return an empty string or 0 or something similar (just a plain simple default value for the *Name*).

If you want to translate, you should use the config `convert` like

```
convert: function(value) {
    App.model.Translation.translate(value)
},
```

Comment: Translation is an Object which has TranslationItems.. And as a default value i do want assign an empty Translation Object...

Comment: I don't understand. Your field `Name` is holding an object in your database ? Fields should be integers, floats, booleans, stings, or another valid datatype.

Comment: My field name is containing an Object Translation which contains an array of TranslationItems where each contains a string and a langcode; i need this to administrate my masterdata where users can enter the names in many languages...

Comment: Sounds like you need a [hasOne](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasOne) kind of association (from Station to Translation) and a [hasMany](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany) association (from Translation to TranslationItem).